# Daily forecast on a PySpark dataframe

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have the following dataframe in PySpark:

`DT_BORD_REF`: Date column for the month
`REF_DATE`: A date reference for current day separating past and future
`PROD_ID`: Product ID
`COMPANY_CODE`: Company ID
`CUSTOMER_CODE`: Customer ID
`MTD_WD`: Month to Date count of working days (Date = DT_BORD_REF)
`QUANTITY`: Number of items sold
`QTE_MTD`: Number of items month to date

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+-------------+------+--------+-------+
|        DT_BORD_REF|           REF_DATE|          PROD_ID|COMPANY_CODE|CUSTOMER_CODE|COUNTRY_ALPHA|MTD_WD|QUANTITY|QTE_MTD|
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+-------------+------+--------+-------+
|2020-11-02 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|     1|     4.0|    4.0|
|2020-11-05 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|     3|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-06 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|     4|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-09 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|     5|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-10 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|     6|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-11 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|     7|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-12 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|     8|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-13 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|     9|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-16 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|    10|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-17 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|    11|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-18 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|    12|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-19 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|    13|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-20 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|    14|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-23 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|    15|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-24 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|    16|    null|    4.0|
|2020-11-25 00:00:00|2020-11-04 00:00:00|          0000043|         503|     KDAI3982|          RUS|    17|    null|    4.0|
```

for `DT_BORD_REF < REF_DATE` all rows are actual sales and do not necessarily occurs every working day. Sometimes happens in non working days too.

for `DT_BORD_REF >= REF_DATE` there are no sales (it's the future)

The objective is to forecast the sales for all future rows using the formula: `QTE_MTD/MTD_WD` calculated on the `REF_DATE` for each product, customer and country.

The QTE_MTD was calculated from QUANTITY column using a window function. I need to divide that for `MTD_WD` on `REF_DATE` which in this exemple is 3

How can I add a column with `MTD_WD` on `REF_DATE` partitioning by product, customer and country?

In other words, I need to add a column with the first occurrence of `MTD_WD` when the condition `DT_BORD_REF > REF_DATE` is met (again, which is 3 in this exemple) for each product, customer and country.

This dataset has millions of row for different products, customers and countries
The working days are provided by country

Hope it was clear :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `first` with `ignorenulls=True`, and `when` with the appropriate condition, to get the first `MTD_WD` where `DT_BORD_REF` > `REF_DATE`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'val',
    F.first(
        F.when(
            F.col('DT_BORD_REF') > F.col('REF_DATE'),
            F.col('MTD_WD')
        ), 
        ignorenulls=True
    ).over(
        Window.partitionBy('PROD_ID','COMPANY_CODE','CUSTOMER_CODE','COUNTRY_ALPHA')
              .orderBy('DT_BORD_REF')
              .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    )
)
```